# How to show tooltip in messagebox for ok and cancel buttons in angularjs. we are using the $dialog message box

Tags: angularjs

I am using the [dialog in angular-ui](https://github.com/thierryc/bootstrap-ui-angularjs/tree/master/src/dialog). I want to have tooltips for the "OK" and "Cancel" button for a dialog, how can I achieve that through AngularJS?

I am using the below code:
var msgbox = this.$dialog.messageBox(
                "confirmation box title",
                "confirmation box message"),
                [
                    { label: "OK", result: '1', cssClass: 'btn' },
                    { label: "Cancel", result: '0', cssClass: 'btn-primary' }
                ]);
and for the label "OK" and label "Canel" i need the tooltip basically the label is in the angular code and not in the html so i am not able to use ng-attr-tooltip attribute.

Answer (score 0):

search for tool tip on the following link

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: I am using the below code ://Below is the code for that

var msgbox = this.$dialog.messageBox(
                "confirmation box title",
                "confirmation box message"),
                [
                    { label: "OK", result: '1', cssClass: 'btn' },
                    { la`enter code here`bel: "Cancel", result: '0', cssClass: 'btn-primary' }
                ]);

//I want to have tooltips for "OK" and "Cancel" button for this dialog. How can we achieve this through Angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own tooltip directive to do this..

You'd need to do the following in the directive's linking function:

- Bind to the `element`'s `'mouseenter'` event to append a tooltip to the DOM
- (optionally) Bind to the `element`'s `'mousemove'` event to change the tooltip's css location if you want it to move with the mouse.
- Bind to the `'element`'s `'mouseleave'` event to remove the tooltip element from the DOM.